# Need help with translating this Korean passage about Nyout

Tags: translation

Would someone be kind enough to translate this paragraph for me, or at least comment on the unclear parts. Google Translate is great but some part seem odd, like "the water supply" :)

Thanks, Joseph

민속학자 안동대 임재해 교수는 그의 책 ≪한국 민속과 오늘의 문화≫에서 “윷놀이”는 우연성과 신명성이 큰 특징이라고 말합니다. 특히 아무리 솜씨 좋은 놀이꾼도, 삶의 지혜를 터득한 할아버지도, 학문이 뛰어난 선비도, 철들지 않은 어린 아이에게 질 수도 있다는 것입니다. 또 윷놀이는 놀이의 기능을 익히고자 오랜 세월과 돈을 투자해야 하는 것도 아니며, 급수가 있는 것도 아닙니다. 또한, 구경꾼도 응원하거나 훈수를 두어도 탓이 되지 않는 놀이입니다. 그래서 윷놀이는 무슨 특수층을 위한 놀이가 아니며, 남녀노소 모두 하나 되어 즐기면 그뿐인 놀이입니다. 다시 말하면 윷놀이는 판소리처럼 추임새 문화의 하나이지요.

In his book `` Korean Folklore and Today's Culture '', folk scholar Prof. Andongdae Lim Jae-hae says that "Yunnori" is a feature of chance and deity. In particular, no matter how skillful the players, grandfathers who have learned the wisdom of life, scholars who are well-educated, they may lose to young children. In addition, it is not necessary to invest many years and money in order to learn the function of play and there is no water supply. It is also a game not to blame even if the onlookers cheer or hunsu. That's why it's not a special play for the special class. In other words, Yutnori is one of the cultures of Chuimsae like Pansori.

Comment: I think it will be easier to understand this text if you breakdown each sentence and translate them separately.

Comment: For your particular question see these meanings of 급수: https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/fef01f8fd83643abba3a21f38cb13822, 
https://en.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koen/28216158cc7d439c865a7c66299a196d

Comment: Prof. Andongdae Lim Jae-hae: 안동대 is 안동대학교 (Andong University) and Prof. Lim Jae-hae is his name.

Comment: It is also a game not to blame even if the onlookers cheer or hunsu.: This sentence basically says onlookers cannot affect the game's outcome (which is a good thing about this game's rules)

Comment: For the last sentence I suggest you try to find out what 추임새 exactly means. In general the last sentence says Yutnori is a communal experience where players and onlookers support each other instead of competing against.

Comment: The term 급수 (ranks) relates to the board game Go (바둑). There is a Wikipedia article on [바둑 급수](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_ranks_and_ratings).

Comment: It is also a game not to blame even if the onlookers cheer or hunsu: so who is "not to blame"? and for what? the players can't blame the spectators? the players can't blame the game?

Comment: "What the onlookers do (cheering and kibitzing) cannot be the *cause* (탓) of a gamer's losing the game."